# Using VSDC to make a GIF and I want to adjust the scale and resolution

Tags: image-quality

Using VSDC to make a GIF and I want to adjust the scale and resolution. I found that I could not adjust the scale and dimension of the images. So I faked it. Using trial and error, I adjusted the size and position of the individual images of the gif.

I did figure out how to make the images fade into the other by doing a transparent transform on each beginning and end of the image appearance on the timeline.

I did figure out how to make the images fade into the other by doing a transparent transform on each beginning and end of the image appearance on the timeline. Using trial and error, I adjusted the size and position of the individual images of the gif.

Have you used VSDC to make a GIF? How did you handle these issues?

My issue is not so much about creating a GIF. I was able to navigate through VSDC and figure out how to save a file as a GIF image. I also learned how to fade one image into another along the timeline. I also learned how to make the video loop.

The only problem I am stumped on right now is how to make the canvas dimension match the size and scale of the image I place on it. How do I do that, please?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing and video software questions are generally off topic here.  Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: I assume the question can be migrated by the moderator... But more than a video question this is a motion graphics question... But what do I know. n_n

Comment: @Rafael Sure, but motion graphics made using VSDC is still video editing. So where do we draw the line? You can use AfterEffects to make motion graphics too, same with Blender.  Also, the "What topics can I ask about" page clearly lists video editing as off-topic.  "What not to ask: video editing – ask on Video Production instead;".

Answer (score 0):

You define the size at the beginning of the project.

[image]

I am assuming you already finished it. See if changing the dimensions does not mess up your project.

Projects tab > Project Explorer Tab > Properties Menu

[image]

If the proportion you want is different than what you already have for example horizontal vs vertical, you need to make the proper adjustments.

---

If your project although different in size, has the correct **horizontal vs vertical proportion** what you can do is resample it after exporting a video.

You can use virtualdub2 for that.

[image]

And export your gif from there.

[image]

---